# what is the significance of newline character in the format string of scanf function?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int a,b;
printf("enter two numbers ");
scanf("%d \n%d",&a,&b);
printf("%d  %d",a,b);
return 0;
}
```

when I give inputs like 3 and 5 , then the issue is that even if I give inputs without any newline character in between them then also the scanf function scans the input value , but in the formal string I have stated that the next input should be scanned after a newline character so how can the next input be scanned just after some few  whitespaces .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

White-space in the [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) format string tells `scanf` (and family) to read and ignore white-space in the input. It doesn't matter what kind of white-space character you use in the format: Space, newlines and tabs are all the same.

However, you don't actually *need* it for all formats. most `scanf` formats automatically reads and ignore leading white-space, including the `"%d"` format.

Comment: So that means newline is also a whitespace ?

Comment: @RadhaGogia That's correct. If you want to know what characters are "space" characters, make a simple test programs that loop over all 127 letters in the basic alphabet and check with [`isspace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace).

Answer (score 1):

The `" \n"` in the `"%d \n%d"` format string will "eat" all whitespace characters as defined by [isspace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace), including newlines.

To force reading the integers off separate lines, use this instead:

```
if(scanf("%d%*[^\n]\n%d",&a,&b) != 2) return EXIT_ERROR;
```